# AJAX form not submitting with wp_mail()

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a form on my page. I am sending data without plugins, using **wp_mail()**. The submit code is in function.php and I am pasting the form as a shortcode on the page. The form works, submits data without AJAX. When I add AJAX code, in devtools it shows that the form has been sent, an alert pops up, but the form does not come to the mail. How can this problem be solved?

```js
// my ajax

$("#contact-form-submit").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var userName = $('#full-name').val();
  var userEmail = $('#email').val();
  var userMessage = $('#message').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
      action: "display_contact_form",
      contact_form: hiddenInput,
      full_name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
      message: userMessage,
    },
    success: function(response) {
      alert("success");
    }
  });
});
```

```js
//function.php

add_shortcode( 'contact-form', 'display_contact_form' );

function display_contact_form() {

    $validation_messages = [];
    $success_message = '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['contact_form'] ) ) {

        //Sanitize the data
        $full_name = isset( $_POST['full_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['full_name'] ) : '';
        $email     = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
        $message   = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['message'] ) : '';

        //Validate the data
        if ( strlen( $full_name ) === 0 ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid name.' );
        }

        if ( strlen( $email ) === 0 or
             ! is_email( $email ) ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid email address.' );
        }

        if ( strlen( $message ) === 0 ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid message.');
        }

        //Send an email to the WordPress administrator if there are no validation errors
        if ( empty( $validation_messages ) ) {

            $mail    = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            $subject = 'New message from ' . $full_name;
            $message = $message . ' - The email address of the customer is: ' . $mail;

            wp_mail( $mail, $subject, $message );

            $success_message = esc_html__( 'Your message has been successfully sent.' );

        }

    }

    //Display the validation errors
    if ( ! empty( $validation_messages ) ) {
        foreach ( $validation_messages as $validation_message ) {
            echo '<div class="validation-message">' . esc_html( $validation_message ) . '</div>';
        }
    }

    //Display the success message
    if ( strlen( $success_message ) > 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="success-message">' . esc_html( $success_message ) . '</div>';
    }

    ?>

    <!-- Echo a container used that will be used for the JavaScript validation -->
    <div id="validation-messages-container"></div>

    <form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"
          method="post">

        <input type="hidden name="contact_form">

        <div class="form-section">
            <label for="full-name"><?php echo esc_html( 'Full Name'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full_name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-section">
            <label for="email"><?php echo esc_html( 'Email' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-section">
            <label for="message"><?php echo esc_html( 'Message'); ?></label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="contact-form-submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <?php

}

add_action('wp_ajax_display_contact_form', 'display_contact_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_contact_form', 'display_contact_form');
```

Comment: Add `contact_form` in your ajax **data** part (otherwise `isset( $_POST['contact_form']` ) will return false) -- for the normal form submission you have <input type="hidden" name="contact_form"> so it works

Comment: _"contact_form: hiddenInput"_ - Where do you define `hiddenInput`? Since that input doesn't have any value, you might just do: `contact_form: 'foo'`